# Given a public key string, how to create an instance of RSAPublicKey

Tags: java, jwt

I have an actual public key string like:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
flajeleofancncMFLDFJOEEFJC9209ueq33rlsjfa3B ...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

In order to create an [auth0/java-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt)-library `Algorithm` to sign my JWT, I need a `java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey`-implementation instance. How would I go about creating that instance given public key string? If it helps, I also have the private key string.
I'm just starting out. So, I'm open to simpler ways to signing my JWT.

Comment: That is probably clear but **java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey** is an interface. Means you won't be able to have an instance of it. You need an actual implementation of it.

Comment: I suggest that you check out the README for the java-awt project that you linked. It gives some information that will hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: @AndiCover, yes, I'm looking for an instance that _implements_ that interface.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, unfortunately, it doesn't. This is all, I'm seeing:
`RSAPublicKey publicKey = //Get the key instance`

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
```

...

```
String algorithm = "RSA" // for example
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
String publicKeyStr = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----f24Defosfvak-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyStr.getBytes());
RSAPublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(keySpec);
```